# C# Static method in interface cannot be accessed from the implementing class

Tags: c#, methods, interface, static

The method `SomeStaticMethod` from interface `IA` is not directly accessible from the class `A` that implemented the interface. Am I missing something?

```cs
public interface IA {
    public static int SomeStaticMethod() => 4;    
}

public class A : IA {
    public static void Bidule() {
        SomeStaticMethod(); //DO NOT COMPILE
        IA.SomeStaticMethod(); //COMPILES
    }
}
```

If the interface `IA` is changed to a class, it works.

```cs
public class IA {
    public static int SomeStaticMethod() => 4;    
}

public class A : IA {
    public static void Bidule() {
        SomeStaticMethod(); //NOW it works
    }
}
```

Comment: *Am I missing something?* yes ... the fact that you can implement 2 different interfaces with the same static method name .. but you can't derive from 2 classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class can implement multiple interfaces. If you defined a static method with the same signature in both interfaces, the compiler couldn't decide which of those should be invoked. It's one of the (many) reasons why most OO languages try to avoid multiple-inheritance, useful as it can be.